# Como utilizar 'atalhos' do Bootstrap no VSCode em arquivos .blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, visual-studio-code

Existe uma extensão chamada Bootstrap 3 Snippets, porém, ela apenas executa os snippets em arquivos HTML.

Como fazer para que isso funcione em arquivos de outras extensões?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize os snippets da extensão de forma manual:

1. Acesse e copie o conteúdo de:
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wcwhitehead/bootstrap-3-snippets/master/snippets/snippets.json
2. Vá em Usar Snippets no seu VSCode:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Clique em `New Global Snippets` e dê um nome a ele.
4. Cole o conteúdo copiado do json e salve o arquivo.
5. Use

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]