# Como auto completar HTML em arquivos .tpl no VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

No meu projeto para redenrizar minhas views, estou usando Smarty, no qual seus arquivos são da extensão `.tpl`. Nesses arquivos, escrevo 80% em HTML, mas está se tornando um trabalho cansativo e lento, pois o VSCode não dá a opção de auto completar as minhas tags.

Existe alguma extensão ou configuração possível para isso?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/456897/vs-code-n%C3%A3o-autocompleta-tags-html-ou-css-em-uma-blade-laravel

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/287219/como-utilizar-atalhos-do-bootstrap-no-vscode-em-arquivos-blade?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das opções é você incluir uma configuração específica no seu arquivo `settings.json`. Existem duas formas de você fazer isso.

### Acessando a tela de "Preferências" do VS CODE

Para acessar as preferências do VS Code, você deve usar o atalho <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (no meu SO é esse atalho, pode variar em outros). Você também pode usar o menu: **<kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd>**.

Ao abrir a tela de configuração, você precisa digitar "files.associations" e adicionar um valor em "Item" e "Value". Os valores são, respectivamente, `*.tpl` e `html`, conforme a imagem  mostrada:

[image: Adicionando configuração específica no VS CODE]

### Editando o `settings.json` diretamente

Se preferir fazer editando o arquivo `settings.json`, você deve clicar no ícone acíma, localizado a direita, chamado "Open Settings (json)".

[image: Ícone de edição do settings.json do VS CODE]

Em seguida, adicione a linha:

```js
    "files.associations": {
        "*.tpl": "html"
    },
```

### Resultado

Após fazer isso, ao digitar qualquer código num arquivo `.tpl`, você vai ter um autocomplete da seguinte forma:

[image: Configurando autocomplete de HTML em outra linguagem]

Comment: Wallace, muito obrigado!